# get the indices of several row names

Tags: r

For the dataframe below, how to get the indices of specific rows?

```
df
name    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5 ...
site1    10    20    12    5     ..
site2    15    NA    11    2     ..
site3    NA    11    21    1     ..
site4    9     18    NA    6     ..
site1    9     15    NA    5     ..
site3    10    18    15    7     ..
```

When I want to choose row indices of site1 and site3, I typed:

```
which(c(df[,1]=='site1',df[,1]=='site3'))
```

Then I checked the results, which is totally different from the combination of
`which(df[,1]=='site1')` and `which(df[,1]=='site3')`
how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Try `which(df[,1]=='site1'|df[,1]=='site3')`. When you concatenate the logical index, the length is doubled and then the `which` statement gets the position based on the new index instead of the original one in your dataset

Comment: `which(df[,1] %in% c("site1","site3"))`

Comment: Thanks. arkun, do you mean the positions of the new index will not represent the original positions?

Comment: @Lily Yes, the `which` is now getting the position based on the concatenated logical index.  May be `c(which(df$name=='site1'), which(df$name=='site3'))` this is what you wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this...

```
> which(df[,1]=="site1"|df[,1]=="site3")
[1] 1 3 5 6
```